# Calculate the integral of a rational function using residues

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I want to calculate integral :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+16}{x^4+10x^2+9}$$
Which because its integrand is an even function of $x$, can be rewritten as $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+16}{x^4+10x^2+9}$$
Consider the function $$f(z)=\frac{z^2+16}{z^4+10z^2+9}$$
The dominator has simple zeros at $z=\pm3i $ and $z=\pm i$.
Let's count
$Res[f(3i)] = \lim_{z \to 3i}\frac{z^1+16}{(z+3i)(z+i)(z-i)} = \frac{7}{48i}$
Similarly, $Res[f(-3i)] = \frac{7}{48i}$

$Res[f(i)] = \frac{15}{16i} = -Res[f(-i)]$.

So, $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+16}{x^4+10x^2+9} = \frac{14\pi}{48i}$$
Is the idea good?
Of course, I am considering the semicircular contour $\gamma_R$, which starts at $R$, traces a semicircle in the upper half plane to $−R$ and then travels back to R along the real axis.
Why this integral is equal to zero if we integrate on semicircle in the upper half plane?

Comment: An intergal of a real function MUST be real. Check your calculations: REcall that Residue formula states that the integral is $2\pi i$ times the sum of all residues INSIDE your contour. Moreover, over the semicircle, you can use the [ML-inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma).

Comment: When doing a problem like this, you should explicitly write down the contour you are using (done), then check the integral on parts you want to ignore go to zero (not done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but the result is not correct. We have $\operatorname{res}_{3i} f=-\frac{7}{48i}$. So assuming the integral along the semicircle goes to zero we get: $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2+16}{x^4+10x^2+9}=\pi i\left(\operatorname{res}_{3i} f+\operatorname{res}_{i} f\right)=\pi i\left(\frac{-7}{48i}+\frac{15}{16i}\right)=\dots$$

We still need to argue why the integral over the semicircle goes to zero. Note for this that $\vert f(z)\vert\leq C\vert z\vert^{-2}$ for large enough $\vert z\vert$ and some constant $C$. So we can bound the integral over the semicircle $\gamma_R$ with radius $R$: $$\left\vert\int_{\gamma_R} f(z)dz\right\vert\leq CR^{-2}\operatorname{length}(\gamma_R)=CR^{-2}\pi R=\frac{C\pi}{R}\to0~~\text{as }R\to\infty $$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+16}{(x^4+10x^2+9)}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+16}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}$$
$$I= \frac{15}{8} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}-\frac{7}{8}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{9+x^2}$$
$$I=\frac{15}{8} \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{7}{8} \frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{19}{24}\pi$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to OP's question. He wants to solve this with residues, not via arctangent function.